# Setsize on joptionpane box

Tags: java

I have the following code. I added a textArea in my panel in joptionpane, but the frame size of box is so small and textArea is not fit in it. So, how can i largen the joptionpane box.

```
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));

        JPanel labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,2,2));
        labels.add(new JLabel("Name", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        labels.add(new JLabel("Description", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        p.add(labels, BorderLayout.WEST);


        JPanel controls = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,4,4));
        JTextField name = new JTextField();
        controls.add(name);
        JTextArea description = new JTextArea();
   //     description.addAncestorListener(new RequestFocusListener(false));
        controls.add(description);
        p.add(controls, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, p, "Create Atomic Action", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

        if(result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
        {
           System.out.println("Yes press Name"+name.getText()+"  "+description.getText());
        }else
            System.out.println("Cancel press");
```

Comment: try using setPreferedSize mthod on textArea

Comment: Can you post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Salman I meant a class that I can copy and paste, without having to add extra code to make it executable.

Answer (score -1):

Besides setting the preferred size, as @dpassy suggested, I added a `ScrollPane` component, so that you can add more text (more than can be shown on the dialog box) and scroll down to the bottom. I, also, changed the layout from `GridLayout` to `BorderLayout` so that the `TextBox` doesn't grow unnecessarily to fill up the space.

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

        JPanel labels = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        labels.add(new JLabel("Name", SwingConstants.RIGHT),BorderLayout.NORTH);
        labels.add(new JLabel("Description", SwingConstants.RIGHT), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p.add(labels, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JPanel controls = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JTextField name = new JTextField();
        controls.add(name, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JTextArea description = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(description);
        // description.addAncestorListener(new RequestFocusListener(false));
        sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
        controls.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p.add(controls, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, p, "Create Atomic Action", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    }
}
```

As a result, it will show this dialog:

[image]

And when you add text inside the `TextArea` it will show the scroll bar too.

[image]